# spring boot (webflux) rest controller get remote IP address

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Using spring boot for simple REST application.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have a simple controller that handles requests.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public BasicDTO getBasic(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        return new BasicDTO();
    }

}
```

The `HttpServletRequest` context does not get injected. How can I inject the request context into the method so that I can access some basic socket details? Thanks.

Comment: How does the "api/test" endpoint get called?

Comment: web browser. why?

Comment: Are you using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest?

Comment: Also how does this method even work? You don't return anything from this method.

Comment: @user2914191 I'm skeptical that it ever gets called, since it shouldn't compile.

Comment: no i omitted the return value but regardless spring will complain that it cant inject

Comment: not sure what you mean by that

Comment: is there any exception ?

Comment: i get an error that says `Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' on public com.BasicDTO com.MainController.getBasic(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception`

Comment: `final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();` might work for you, although if you're in a non-servlet context, not so much.

Comment: I don't know about why you guys are saying it cannot be injected. I just implemented a similar example and I can inject it. http://prntscr.com/kqiksp

Comment: did you use `spring-boot-starter-webflux`? im missing the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, not sure if i need it. i configured spring for a react app

Comment: Apologies, I must have overlooked it. I have removed my answer.

Comment: Show your imports please :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at your `pom.xml` it uses `spring-boot-starter-webflux` so you must use `ServerHttpRequest` instead of `HttpServletRequest`.

Or include,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and remove `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependency.

Comment: bingo. specifying `ServerHttpRequest request` in my method correctly injects `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`.

Comment: for anyone who needs more details, obtain IP address with `request.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress()`